# Using Google maps API via SSL

Tags: ssl, google-maps-api-3

So, I know just recently that google maps API is now available in SSL ([here](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/03/maps-apis-over-ssl-now-available-to-all.html)).

My question is, how do I *retro-fit* my http google maps api script to use this?

So my http Google maps API script call looks like this:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=3&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=########
```

They suggest via [this](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#HTTPS) link that to use SSL it should be this:

```
https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false
```

I've tried retro-fitting this into my old URL format like so:

```
https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=########
```

but that no longer displays the map.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what the URL should be?

Thanks

Comment: Any errors in your JavaScript console log?  Do you have a link to the app with the new URL in it so we can see what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this line:
`https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.5&sensor=true`
Google btw suggests that you explicitly enter what version of the api you are going to use. Just entering v=3 will always return the latest version, at the moment 3.5. I believe that the current stable version is 3.3.
As Trott wrote in his answer, api key is no longer needed.

Comment: Good to know - as a side note, the new google maps API is much faster - looks to be at least 30% improvement on v2

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an API key to use v3, but I suppose it probably doesn't hurt.  General things to try:

1. Open your browser's JavaScript console and see if it is reporting any problems when you load the page.
2. Remove the API key
3. Change `&amp;` to just `&`
4. Copy and paste the exact link text you put above into your code, because that link text is working for me.  I'm referring to this:

`https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=########`

Of course, change ######## to your API key (or just remove it altogether).

Comment: Thanks.  The problem turned out to be a revision to the API  which I hadn't accounted for.  I'll remember to put in the specific version to future-proof against further revisions...

Comment: @schlock If you liked an answer and considered it an answer then please upvote or set it as answer. If you managed to solve it yourself then post answer to your own answer.